# Decoding error (Saving HTTP responses (if changed) to CSV)

Tags: python, csv

I am Python newbie and still trying to find my way to get started withcreating small scripts.

It is difficult to figure out errors, I kept searching, but cannot find a solution. Please, have a look

I am getting this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "http-bulk-check.py", line 10, in <module>
 for line in iter(urls):
 File "C:\python\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
   return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
   UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position        16: character maps to <undefined>
```

My code:

```
import requests
import csv
import re
import os

urlinput = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), input('Enter input text file: '))
urls = open(urlinput, "r")
outputcsv = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), input('Enter a filename (minus file extension): ')+'.csv')
f = csv.writer(open(outputcsv, "w+", newline="\n", encoding="utf-8"))
for line in iter(urls):
values = {'url' : line}
response = requests.head('url', allow_redirects=True, headers={"user-agent": "Googlebot"})
if response.history:
   print ("Request was redirected")
   for resp in response.history:
       print (resp.status_code, resp.url)
       print ("Final destination:")
       print (response.status_code, response.url)
   else:
       print (checked_url)
       print ("Request was not redirected"),
 print ("Writing to " + outputcsv + " complete.")
```

What I am trying to accomplish with this script:

- I have a list of urls saved in csv
- I want to check their HTTP with Googlebot User agent
- I want to save the URLs, response code in a new Excel file ( if the HTTP has changed and it is not 200), and I want to record the new HTTP + the new URL in a new csv file (or the same one, I just don't know how).

Comment: This is Python 3.5

Comment: Ahh... Then look at the contents of your uls.file. It is not formatted as simple ascii

Comment: I tried and nothing has changed, I am still getting the same error message :(